# Почему при сравнении по equals не происходит проверка hashCode (в частности, в классе String)

Tags: java, строки, hashcode, equals

Если два объекта равны с точки зрения equals, то значения, возвращаемые hashCode, также будут одинаковые. Следовательно, если у двух объектов разные хэши, то объекты должны считаться разными с точки зрения equals. Почему же во всех встреченных мною реализациях equals нет проверки на несовпадение по хэшу? Особенно, необъяснимо для меня отсутствие проверки хешей при сравнении неизменяемых объектов, в которых хэш кэшируется в момент создания. Яркий пример String.

Если сравниваются две огромные строки, у которых уже вычислен хэш, и этот хэш разный, то почему бы после проверки на "==" не проверить, что хеши различаются и сразу вернуть false.

Понимаю, что упускаю какой-то важный решающий момент, но поймать его не могу.

Comment: Очевидно упускаете момент коллизии хэша, если вас устраивает это досадное допущение - проверяйте равенство хешей явно :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Не совсем понимаю, о чем вы. Я полагал, что коллизия хэша - это когда 2 объекта разные, но имеют одинаковый хеш. Я же спрашиваю, почему нельзя возвращать false сразу, если у двух объектов разные хэши, ведь это означает, что и сами объекты не равны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При проверках на `.equals()` не в коллекциях `HashSet` или `HashMap` у вас получится, что вы при каждой проверке заново рассчитываете хэш обоих сравниваемых значений, само по себе это не ускорит сравнение, а наоборот добавит лишний этап.

С другой стороны, если объекты имеют сложную структуру (или это какие-то большие объекты), можно хранить вычисленный хэш внутри объекта (желательно, чтобы объект был не модифицируемым, иначе придется это значение при каждом изменении пересчитывать). Тогда сравнение неравных объектов действительно будет завершаться быстрее.

**Т.е. если сильно нужно, то можно добавить в классе отдельное поле хэша, и по нему внутри `equals` сравнивать. Но сама функция `hashCode` обычно пересчитывает хэш заново, поэтому во всех реализациях классов ее вызов в `equals` скорее ухудшит производительность, а не улучшит.**

Все, конечно, зависит от конкретной реализации. Можно и в `hashCode` не пересчитывать хэш заново, а брать из поля, но в хранимом поле хэша имеет смысл только если объект немодифицируемый, иначе придется хэш пересчитывать при каждой модификации (или как-то буферизировать модификации, в общем - много нюансов).

А когда хранимого хэша нет, то `hashCode` будет пересчитывать хэш от всех значимых полей, тогда какой смысл в его вызове, если можно просто эти же поля сравнить напрямую.

---

По поводу строк. На коротких строках время выполнения методов `equals` и `hashCode` будет сопоставимо, получается добавление `hashCode` (условно) удвоит время сравнения. Это может ухудшить производительность при сравнении большого количества мелких строк. Поэтому проверку `hashCode` и нет смысла добавлять.

А на длинных строках вы можете самостоятельно добавить проверку хэша, никто не мешает вам это сделать.

Comment: Кажется немного путано получилось, но надеюсь, мысль донес.

Comment: Совсем не путанно. Разложили все по полочкам. Спасибо большое за ответ! Я правда думал, что посчитать хэши и сравнить их будет быстрее, чем сравнивать все значимые поля (ведь сравнение на уровне инструкций процессора гораздо более тяжелая операция, чем арифметические, насколько мне известно). Но видимо профита и правда от этого не много, а в случае совпадения хешей так и вообще гарантированно будет выполнена пустая работа. Так что да. Теперь все понятно. Еще раз спасибо за ваш развернутый ответ!

Comment: @АндрейКопылов если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым, для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятен вопрос. Оператор "==" не проверяет "одиннаковость" объектов, он проверяет ссылаются ли переменные на один и тот же объект.

> Почему же во всех встреченных мною реализациях equals нет проверки на
> несовпадение по хэшу?

Проверка по equals долгая. Если у объекта переопределены методы equals и hashCode, при сравнении объектов сам метод equals вызовется только в случае, если их hashCode совпали. Если hashCode не совпали, то до метода equals() дело не доходит, возвращается значение false. Считайте процесс двухэтапным. Первый этап (быстрый) сравниваются hash. Если они НЕ равны друг другу - возвращается false. Если равны - запускается второй этап (медленный) - метод equals(). И за ним уже окончательное решение равны ли объекты или нет. Второй этап запускается чтобы предотвратить "коллизию". Коллизия - это момент, когда у объектов hash совпадает, но они не равны. Такое достаточно редко, но бывает. Объясняется это тем, что hashCode() возвращает int число. То есть это конечное значение. А объектов вы можете создать бесконечное колличество. То есть ситуация при которой два разных объекта будут иметь одинаковый hash - реальна. Вот для таких целей и существует метод equals. Больше он, фактически, не вызывается. Так, как он, как я указал выше, куда медленней чем hash.

Comment: Ну я вроде все достаточно подробно описал. Если вы не поняли про оператор "==", то имелось ввиду, что проверка на неравенство хешей была бы логична сразу после проверки на "==", которая есть внутри всех реализаций equals. И не могли бы вы немного подробнее остановиться на двухэтапности вызова equals'а. Каким образом перед вызовом equals происходит проверка на хэш, если явно он нигде не вызывается?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1422685/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-equals-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8f-hashcode-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%82/1422843#1422843

Comment: Тут я описывал логику, и привел пример в конце. По которому видно принцип работы связки hashCode - equals()

Comment: Вы отвечаете не на тот вопрос, который я задал. Я спрашивал конкретно про метод equals, а не про поиск по ключу в хэш-таблицах. Там, понятно дело, сначала идет проверка по хэшу. Я cправшиваю про сам метод equals, почему внутри него нет проверки на hash. Ведь сравнение срок  - это не только поиск в хеш-мапах и т.п.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду, чтобы прописать в начале метода equals() еще и сравнению по hashCode - то можно конечно, но фактически а какой смысл? Сравнение двух объектов не особо длительный процесс. Много времени вы тут не сэкономите. О времени стоит думать как раз во время работ с hash таблицами. То есть вы конечно можете добавить в equals проверку по hash. И это будет работать, но смысла нет

Comment: Понял. Думал, что хэш все-таки быстрее выполняется, чем сравнение каждого поля. но видимо, это не так. Спасибо за ваши ответы!

Comment: @АндрейКопылов это так. Хэш действительно быстрее. Но на нескольких объектах эта разница минимальна и не играет никакой роли. О времени работы есть смысл задумываться, только когда сравнений происходит много. (те же хэш таблицы - а там уже это итак организовано, как я описал выше).